# Getting location on first boot FC also and random FC's on some devices

Tags: android

I am getting the current location with the following code but this is causing FC if there is no last known location. Also some devices like Motorola atrix crash if they open this activity.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

Is there a better way of getting the current location with out crashing my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop it from crashing your application, put the code within a try/catch block.  Android apps "force close" when an exception occurs and is not caught.  If you find that it throws an error because the data is not ready yet, you can try again shortly after the first exception is caught.

Comment: This seems to fix the power up open app FC. Not sure about the issue on Motorola Atrix since i have Nexus S but thank you I did think about that.